# Android Studio neither Emulator not Real device working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing this issue after recently updates of android studio neither real device nor emulator is working just a CMD popup appears for some milliseconds(Too quick to read). 
PS: I have already enabled USB debugging 
Completely reinstalled android studio and HAXM.

Comment: You're going to need to provide some kind of error message if you want someone to be able to help you

Comment: As mentioned CMD popup apears just for some millis I just see Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0 and also my real device is not being detected

Comment: But it is detected in ADB 
'C:\Users\Tanveer>adb devices
List of devices attached
5c9ca65 device'

Comment: What happens when you try running to a real device? It pops up a command prompt window?

Comment: Android Studio is not even showing real device while it is being show in adb devices

Comment: There are some bugs in latest platform tools I have updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix that worked for me

1st Close Android Studio

2nd Open CMD and write: taskkill /f /im adb.exe

3rd Download this file: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip

4th Go to

C:\Users[your-username]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

and replace the "platform-tools" folder with the new one that you just downloaded.